# What are HTML meta tags date, search_date, and DC.title?

Tags: seo, meta-tags, tags

What are purpose of these tags?  What is meaning of `DC.title`?

I collected the tags from this [github source](https://gist.github.com/abdullahalnoor/5a4694197f113d13179b96c78645885b)

```
<meta name='date' content='Sep. 27, 2010'>
<meta name='search_date' content='2010-09-27'>
<meta name='DC.title' content='Unstoppable Robot Ninja'>
```

Comment: You tagged this as "SEO", but I doubt that those meta tags have any influence on search engines.   My guess is that they are for some other purpose.

Comment: @Stephen Ostermiller♦ Actually I was not sure about it .... I write about it that  _What are purpose of these tags?_  finally I now that `Dublin Core or DC.title` will not help  for _SEO_  but about others two  tags, I did not know anything ?

Comment: Are you talking about tags or are you talking about attribute values? In your question title, you ask about tags, in your first paragraph, you ask about tags, in your second paragraph, you ask about tags, but the code you posted shows attribute values.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag this the rules how we will write `meta tag`.. example as `<meta name="description" content="Free Web tutorials">` [source](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp)...

Comment: https://gist.github.com/whitingx/3840905 and https://gist.github.com/kevinSuttle/1997924 : May this will help you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can read about the Dublin Core Metadata Element Set at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dublin_Core

It is a set of fifteen "core" elements (properties) for describing resources. DC:title is one of those elements, all of which are listed at Wikipedia.

This fifteen-element Dublin Core has been formally standardized as ISO 15836, ANSI/NISO Z39.85, and IETF RFC 5013. The core properties are part of a larger set of DCMI Metadata Terms. "Dublin Core" is also used as an adjective for Dublin Core metadata, a style of metadata that draws on multiple RDF vocabularies, packaged and constrained in Dublin Core application profiles.

The resources described using the Dublin Core may be digital resources (video, images, web pages, etc), as well as physical resources such as books or CDs, and objects like artworks.

Dublin Core metadata may be used for multiple purposes, from simple resource description to combining metadata vocabularies of different metadata standards, to providing interoperability for metadata vocabularies in the linked data cloud and Semantic Web implementations.

Comment: what are  date,search_date tags ?

Comment: You give no information about what the tags are from and the source is  behind a paywall.  So it is hard to give you an answer.